# Disable Cloud Bigtable cluster to avoid getting billed, but without deleting data

Tags: billing, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I have created a development Cloud Bigtable cluster and would like to disable this when I am not working on it to avoid getting billed, but the only option I see is to delete the cluster; doing this will require me to recreate the tables which I don't want to do.

Is there a way to disable the Cloud Bigtable cluster and enable them only during the time I work on it?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is not currently a way to disable a cluster and just maintain the tables and data.  You can [export data](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/exporting-sequence-files) if need be, or create a script using the [`cbt` command line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart-cbt) to quickly restore your cluster.

Comment: Thank you, but by design should'nt there be a way to disable clusters like there is for other services. Anyway is this being planned cause typically every development project will have non active hrs and hence it is fair to not get billed during the idle time, as along as the development teams shutdown/disable the service.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't disable Google Cloud SQL instances, Google Cloud Storage or Spanner. You just can delete them. And this makes sense, here you are paying as per having a data stored in an infrastructure with a special features. So, even if you disable communications, you will still have this data stored in this special infrastructure. And If you don't want have the data here, then you should migrate during this periods, does this make sense to you?

Comment: @Temu : Your comment may not make sense. Cloud SQL , BigTable, Spanner all come with Storage, which you should be billed. However, they do come with Compute Instance to host the DB as well. I think it is sensible to be able to stop or pause the instance so, the bill will not be too high.

Comment: I see there's indeed a STOP button for Cloud SQL instances.